# XCode AutoLayout Saving Problems

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm having a nagging issue with AutoLayout.  So...

1. I fired up Xcode and what do you know I have 50+ new layout
   warnings all in Regular Width and Regular Height mode (for iPads).
2. I make corrections that get rid of the warnings and save.
3. I quit and re-open Xcode and the warnings are all back as if I never
   did a thing...

What. The. Expletive.

Has anyone else had this issue OS is 10.9.5 and Xcode is 6.1.1.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Just curious: What happens if you ignore the warnings?

Comment: Nothing. It runs just fine. But it looks horrible in Interface Builder with all the yellow-ish dashed lines. It's so annoying after putting in all that effort. I was fairly close to submitting this to the app store too.  It's my first app. Would they still accept it with all this crap?

Comment: What I'm trying to determine is whether the warnings are correct - as opposed to some kind of bug in Xcode / Interface Builder. Have you checked the running app to see whether there are ambiguities in your layout?

Comment: There are no ambiguities when I run it on my iPad. :( This is actually only a recent thing in XCode.  I've been working on this for months and never had this issue. :( Thanks, btw, for your time.

Comment: If there are no ambiguities, ignore the warnings and file a bug. (You might open the project with Xcode 6.2 beta just to see if this is fixed there.)

Comment: Upvoting your comment simply b/c I don't know if I would've thought (or had the confidence) to send a bug report. I figure 100% of my issues are/would be due to my lack of familiarity. But this one seems absurd since it's worked for months. Only difference is I provisioned a new device and updated to Yosemite, nothing else... womp womp.

Comment: Tried 6.2 beta and same thing...why on earth would saved changes revert back?

Comment: Xcode 6.3 Beta 1 – the bug is still there.

Comment: Tried Xcode 6.3 release today and it's not fixed yet. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the version of xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b)
Unfortunately I was unable to find a permanent solution (I think it's a bug in xcode) But I managed to find a small solution that allows you to continue working without fix every time the warnings. You must change the type of layout from the original (wCompact hRegular) and immediately return back to the original layout. Magically disappear all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The orange lines are indicators that you have not set enough constraints.  I've worked with Autolayout a lot and in my experience, it's pretty reliable when it gives you orange lines.  If there is no ambiguity, the lines should be blue.

Comment: I dig it. But I fix the constraints and hit save.  Voila they are gone. I save and quit and re-open and it's like I never changed anything.  For example, when I switch to edit in Regular Width and Regular Height I change my UIImage to 800 by 800 since I have it 100% of the width and height of the View Controller.  When i save and reopen though it goes back to 600 in the same reg height and reg width.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. However, this is a mere experience but I thing it is trying to turn the size classes to the default size class and creating this issue.

If you have created an universal project, your default size classs should be wAny hAny. In such case, if you change the size class to wRegular hRegular and set the layouts even properly, you will get warnings as soon as you reopen the xCode project, as it will give you these warnings. That is why, when you run the app, everything is fine because it got the layout properly, but the warnings may reappear as it is trying to adjust the layouts for the default size classes which is wAny hAny.

My suggestion would be to change the size classes to its default and then fix the warnings. That is also a standard practise.